# Keyboard Char C does not work in Visual Studio. Works in all other programs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard

I can not type the letter C or c in Visual Studio on my home computer. If I open Word, notepad or any other program the letter c works.

I have three computers, two for home and one for work all running Windows 10. I have no issues with the keyboard in two of the environments and I have the exact same add-ins.

Is there a way to reset the keyboard or to run diagnostics in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

I kept looking at my screen when in Visual Studio and I noticed at the bottom of my screen a little window that said: C entered waiting for the second character.

I looked up what to do. From the file menu select preferences which is under save, save as and autosave.

Select keyboard shortcuts.

I had a definition for CF Docs that started with the letter C and for some reason was missing the second character.

I removed that shortcut and voila I can now type the letter C!

Yay!

I hope my post and my answer helps someone.